# How to debug Laravel app in PHPStorm?

Tags: php, laravel, xdebug

I have a AngularJS + Laravel application and not able to setup debugging.
On project root folder I have a PHP file and the debugger breaks at this file always. I use PHPStorm and have unchecked the "First Line Setting"

### server.php

```
<?php
$uri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$uri = urldecode($uri);
$paths = require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/paths.php';
$requested = $paths['public'].$uri;

// This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the  
// built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
// application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
if ($uri !== '/' and file_exists($requested))
{
    return false;
}
require_once $paths['public'].'/index.php';
```

## Xdebug Configuration

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
```

I use `php artisan serve` on my local dev machine.

Comment: So what is not working? You say you cannot set up debugging but the debugger correctly breaks in the code?

Comment: https://laravelista.com/debugging-a-laravel-web-application-with-phpstorm-on-homestead/ check this out it might help

Answer (score 1):

my Xdebug Conf.

[XDebug]

```
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
;xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
;xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
;xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
;xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9001
;xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.idekey = "PhpStorm"
```

and debug settings on phpstorm
[image]

then put breakpoints anywhere on routes.php. 
start debug and check url port, abc....com...../rapor?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=12360 <= its changes every time.